# Handling automatically notification data on iOS when app is in foreground state

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification, react-native-push-notification

Using [react-native-push-notification-ios](https://github.com/react-native-push-notification-ios/push-notification-ios), I would like the notification to arrive, not be shown and the notification data to be passed to the React Native layer to the onNotification function.

To do this I have removed **UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert** from the **userNotificationCenter: willPresentNotification: withCompletionHandler** function. However, I am not sure how to proceed for the object of the notification to be handled automatically delivered to React Native.

How can I do that?

The code presented below is what I am currently using. It works when notifications arrive, but they are not passed to React Native.

```
//Called when a notification is delivered to a foreground app.
-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
      willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification
        withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler
{
  NSLog(@" Notification received!");
  completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionSound | UNNotificationPresentationOptionBadge);
}
```

---

### Update 1

I found a way to handle directly the notification, however its contents seems to be empty:

The code I adjusted above:

```
-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
      willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification
        withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler
{
  NSLog(@" Notification received in foreground!");
  completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionSound | UNNotificationPresentationOptionBadge);
  NSDictionary *dict = @{ @"key" : @"asd", @"key2" : @"qwe"}; // This is a test, this object is correctly passed to React Native
  NSLog(@"notification.request: %@", notification.request);
  [RNCPushNotificationIOS didReceiveRemoteNotification:dict ];
}
```

The result I get printed out in the Xcode console:

```
notification.request: <UNNotificationRequest: 0x28204e640; identifier: B1C6AF87-53AE-4AD0-BE68-A53E663ED2AA, content: <UNNotificationContent: 0x281504680; title: (null), subtitle: (null), body: <redacted>, summaryArgument: , summaryArgumentCount: 0, categoryIdentifier: , launchImageName: , threadIdentifier: , attachments: (
), badge: 1, sound: <UNNotificationSound: 0x2805001c0>, realert: 0, trigger: <UNPushNotificationTrigger: 0x282c18270; contentAvailable: NO, mutableContent: NO>>
```

Finally React Native side I see "notification" coming, obviously it is empty as described above.

How can I get notification data here?

Answer (score 0):

Found fix [here](https://github.com/react-native-push-notification-ios/push-notification-ios/issues/256#issuecomment-863909897).

```
  NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo;

  [RNCPushNotificationIOS didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:^void (UIBackgroundFetchResult result){}];
  completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionNone);
```